# VirtualBox Shared Folder Not Accessible By Apache2

Tags: windows, apache, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I know there are a lot of posts on this issue but none of them address the issue I'm having. I am trying to set up a virtual machine following a tutorial on Lynda.com.

Host is a Surface Pro 2 running Windows 10, guest is Virtual Box 5.0.4 with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. People have had a lot of issues with VirtualBox on Windows 10 but mine installed just fine, I have made it all the way to installing Apache, MySQL etc and I'm able to access the Apache2 server status page on my local browser. I don't seem to be having any port issues and I've followed the tutorial's instructions which were step by step.

The issue I'm having is that I can't access the shared folder. I'm ready to configure PHP and I can't access a file placed in the shared folder, even though I've followed all the directions exactly. The shared folder shows up in the VM manager console with the correct path, but when I place a file in the shared folder and try to hit it through the browser on the host machine I get a 404 error. I've gone over the steps to configure the apache server several times, and it looks like I have everything correct:

```
**blakers**@sandbox:~$ cd /media/**sf_vbsandbox**
blakers@sandbox:/media/sf_vbsandbox$ id
uid=1000(blakers) gid=1000(blakers)             groups=1000(blakers),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),    109(sambashare),**999(vboxsf)**
blakers@sandbox:/media/sf_vbsandbox$ **getent group vboxsf
vboxsf:x:999:blakers,www-data**
```

This is from sites-available/vboxsf.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8282>
  ServerName sandbox
  ServerAlias *.dev

  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-access.log combined

  RewriteEngine On

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Directory /media/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted

  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Location>

  UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /media/sf_%1
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

hi the problem is in this line :

VirtualDocumentRoot /media/sf_%1 , change this folder to be named like the folder that you are sharing. if its called "vbsandbox" then sf_vbsandbox.

you can confirm by:

ls -la /media/
then the folder name will be there.

you will have to restart apache at the end

sudo service apache2 restart